# Call two methods of the same class

Tags: php

### The goal

Call two methods of the same class.

### The problem

I'm getting this error on **`index.php`**:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in [...] on line 3

### What's happening

This is my **index.php**:

```
<?php
    $dinosaur = new \Animals\Dinosaur;
    echo $dinosaur->talk()->opinionAboutSashaGrey;
    echo $dinosaur->talk()->opinionAboutLife;
```

And this is the implementation of the methods:

```
<?php

namespace Animals;

class Dinosaur extends Animal
{

[...]

    public function talk()
    {
        $this->database->query("CALL getDinosaurDialogs();");
        return $this->database->fetchRowAsObject();
    }

[...]

}
```

And the application always shows just the first message (In this case, the Dinosaur's opinion about [Sasha Grey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasha_Grey)).

Someone can give me an idea of how can I solve the problem?

### Debug spotlight

```
[...]
    var_dump($dinosaur->talk());
[...]
```

Returns me `NULL`.

Comment: +1 for the funny code sample.

Comment: Is the error in your index.php or the Dinosaur class?

Comment: I've updated the post. Take a look!

Comment: Are we assuming `$dinosaur->eat("Apple");` is line 11?

Comment: Does error disappear after removing line `$dinosaur->dance("Michael Jackson");` ?

Comment: @h2ooooooo - if it isn't, that would be a fatal, not notice :p

Comment: The problem is that Dinosaur is extinct :|

Comment: Updates make it no clearer. Show us lines 0 - 11.

Comment: Yes, @Narek, the error goes away. But if I change the position of `dance`'s method for the `eat`'s method, the `eat`'s method will be registered on the database.

Comment: The problem is that Michael Jackson is extinct

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo You're completely correct :)

Comment: This might sound 'wild' (see what I did there, Dinosaurs, wild, nevermind)...but what happens if you add the word 'return' before the $this->database lines in the functions?

Comment: Guys, I updated the post again, now with more specific details, like the correct line and showing a message. The problem is on message's displaying. Some suggestions by now?

Comment: Make `$dinosaur->dance("Michael Jackson"); var_dump($dinosaur)` and show output.

Comment: Does `$talk = $dinosaur->talk(); echo $talk -> opinionAboutLife;` work? What says `$talk = $dinosaur->talk(); var_dump($talk)`

Comment: Please add the output of `var_dump($dinosaur->talk());`.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton The output is empty.

Comment: I assume `$this->database->fetchRowAsObject();` is the problem, it doesn't return anything

Comment: Maybe you are right, @Reeno. But `fetchRowAsObject` is being a problem for the second time that it is called.

Answer (score 1):

```
use \Animals\Dinosaur as Dinosaur; 

$dinosaur = new Dinosaur();
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `$dinosaur = new \Animals\Dinosaur;`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by `$this->database->fetchRowAsObject()` returning `null`, which you're then trying to access properties of. `null` obviously isn't an object (and so doesn't have properties), so PHP raises an E_NOTICE.

You need to find out why `fetchRowAsObject()` is returning `null` - is your stored procedure failing, or are you not retrieving its output properly?

Comment: As I said, George, the sequence is affecting the code's behavior. Both procedures are correct, but if I change `echo $dinosaur->talk()->opinionAboutSashaGrey;` for `echo $dinosaur->talk()->opinionAboutLife;`, then I'll get the Dinosaur's opinion about life.

Comment: Didn't you say the output of `var_dump($dinosaur->talk());` is `null`?

Comment: Yeah, it's `NULL`. But what I'm trying to say is that the position of method's call is compromising its behavior and **I want to know why**.